# Receive JSON via POST using HttpUrlConnection on Android

Tags: android, json, post, httpurlconnection

I wanted to send and receive JSON to a REST service using the POST method.
My REST service is set up such that if I send a JSON using the POST method, it will return a JSON. But I'm not able to access the received JSON since the getInputStream() method is not returning the data.
This is the code I'm using to make the POST call

```
public String postCall(String reqUrl,JSONObject jsonObject){
    String response;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String json = jsonObject.toString();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(json);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        int HttpResult = conn.getResponseCode();
        response = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Method for converting the stream to a string is as follows

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I've tested the REST service using a chrome extension, and the JSON is being received successfully.
Is there any way I can receive JSON via the POST method?

Comment: where re you running this call? can we get a bigger picture of your code?

Comment: I'm running this in an AsyncTask to update data on my local database. The REST Service is made on Spring and Hibernate

Comment: Do you get a 200 response code?

Comment: I'm able to get the respective response codes like 200, 403, 500, etc. But can't access the JSON. Whenever I try to use the getInputStream() method, it throws the code to the catch block

Comment: You should consider to use Retrofit library. It makes it really easy to communicate with an REST API because it handles all the http and converting stuff. See here for an example: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: Exception or IOException? And what is the exception message?